# Math.min Error - Exercise Error

Tags: java

When I typed in my answer i got this:

```
The given method does not accept the given parameter types.
no suitable method found for min(int,int,int)
    Math.min(species, Q13, shadow);
        ^
    method Math.min(double,double) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Math.min(float,float) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Math.min(int,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Math.min(long,long) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Any idea how I can fix the aforementioned error? I'm new to this site and the Java programming language and I'm very confused on how to fix this error.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Math.min()` only takes two arguments, and you are passing three.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could create your own min function, something like:

```
public static int min(int... params) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int param : params) {
        if (param < min)
            min = param;
    }
    return min;
}
```

This is not as fancy as functional programming, but it's still compatible to Java7 for those that for one reason or another cannot still use Java8 in some projects.

Or you could just use Apache Commons ObjectUtils.min generic function:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T min(T... values)
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#min-T...-

Comment: I'm not understanding also why I can only post one question every 90 minutes.

Comment: @ForbiddenKraken Sorry for the trouble my friend, but this is to avoid spam from new users. Once you have enough reputation(125), you can post multiple times under a minute.

Answer (score 0):

[`Math.min(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) does not take three (or more) arguments. It only takes two. Change

```
int variable = Math.min(species, Q13, shadow);
```

to

```
int variable = Math.min(species, Math.min(Q13, shadow));
```

Comment: I'm gettin gthis:

Comment: You may have forgotten to include a ) right-parenthesis to match an opening ( left-parenthesis earlier in the code.
')' expected
    int returnProblem = (species, Math.min(Q13, shadow));

Answer (score 0):

`Math.min` is only limited to two arguments, you can either pass the result of one `Math.min` into another `Math.min` call just as Elliott has shown in his answer or you can do:

```
int min = IntStream.of(species, Q13, shadow).min().getAsInt();
```

Comment: I'm new to this site btw, so how come i can only post once every 90 minutes? That's not right.

Comment: I mean ask a question every 90 minutes